# Is there a way to put switches at the end when using OS X command-line?

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, unix

For example:

```
rm long/path/to/some/dir  -r
```

instead of:

```
rm  -r  long/path/to/some/dir
```

Is it possible to make it work like that, as in GNU command line utils?

TIA, Karol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately the answer is negative unless you are willing to switch to GNU command line utilities. OS/X command line tools derive from BSD sources which process command line arguments differently. This all boils down to usage of the library calls like `getopt()` in the standard C-library. OS/X command line tools use the standard library functions whereas GNU command line tools use their own, similar, but slightly more "advanced" version of `getopt()` and companions.

That said, you could work around that by installing [GNU coreutils](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Core_Utilities). One way of doing that would be to use [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/). That, of course, is not the same thing as making OS/X provided BSD command line utilities to the parse command line like the GNU command line utilities do.